# How to set a style for usercontrol in application setting?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, mvvmcross

[My main idea of this is to set visible/hidden for a usercontrol. I used WPF with Mvvmcross.]

I have a user control call SpinningWheelUserControl. I want to visible/hide it with the datatrigger. Below is my xaml code in App.xaml

In App.xaml I have added the namespace of the usercontrol as below.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControl"
```

The following is a style setting for my usercontrol.

```
<Style x:Key="SpinningWheel" TargetType="{x:Type local:SpinningWheelUserControl}" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

There is a class for SpinningWheel

```
public class SpinningWheelViewModel 
    : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

In a constructor of parent class, i use like this code

```
SpinningWheel = new SpinningWheelViewModel();
SpinningWheel.IsVisible = false;
```

The usercontrol is hidden for a first running. But when I change the IsVisble to true, it has no change.

```
SpinningWheel.IsVisible = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `Visibility` instead of `IsVisible` like this:

```
SpinningWheel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

---

Oh now i see, you are setting your custom `IsVisibility` instead of UIElement property.

Issue with your code is you haven't raised `PropertyChanged` to let UI know that some property change in underlying source object.

```
private bool isVisible;
public bool IsVisible
{
   get { return isVisible;}
   set
   {
      if(isVisible != value)
      {
         isVisible = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("IsVisible");
      }
   }
}
```

**Assuming you have implemented [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your class.**

Comment: I cannot use the visibility because the core project is a portable class that i will use for other platform.

Comment: Thank so much. I forgot to add RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsVisible) inside a set block.

Answer (score 1):

This n+1 video called [N=34 : a data-bound busy dialog](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=6fNXGErr9to&t=1732s) shows exactly how to do what you are trying to do.